# Javascript to hide part of form on radio button change

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the below html form and need to write javascript to hide different parts of the form depending on the top radio button selected.

```
<form action="" method="post">

    <label for="number">Number of guests: *
        <input name="number" type="radio" value="1" />1
        <input name="number" type="radio" value="2" />2
        <input name="number" type="radio" value="3" />3
        <input name="number" type="radio" value="4" />4
        <input name="number" type="radio" value="5" />5
    </lable>

    <div id="rsvp1">
        <label for="name">Name: *
            <input name="name" type="text" value="" />
        </label>

        <label for="attending">Attending?: *
            <input name="attending" type="radio" value="Yes" />Yes
            <input name="attending" type="radio" value="No" />No
        </label>
        <label for="dietary">Dietary Requirements?: *
            <input type="checkbox" name="dietary" value="veggie">Veggie<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="dietary" value="allergies">Allergies (Please State)<br>
            <textarea style="margin: 2px; width: 177px; height: 34px;" name="allergies"></textarea>
        </label>



        <label for="notes">Notes (high chair/booster seat/childs meal/ etc.): *
            <textarea style="margin: 2px; width: 177px; height: 34px;" name="notes"></textarea>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div id="rsvp2">
        <label for="name1">Name: *
            <input name="name1" type="text" value="" />
        </label>

        <label for="attending1">Attending?: *
            <input name="attending1" type="radio" value="Yes" />Yes
            <input name="attending1" type="radio" value="No" />No
        </label>
        <label for="dietary1">Dietary Requirements?: *
            <input type="checkbox" name="dietary1" value="veggie">Veggie<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="dietary1" value="allergies">Allergies (Please State)<br>
            <textarea style="margin: 2px; width: 177px; height: 34px;" name="allergies1"></textarea>
        </label>



        <label for="notes1">Notes (high chair/booster seat/childs meal/ etc.): *
            <textarea style="margin: 2px; width: 177px; height: 34px;" name="notes1"></textarea>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div id="rsvp3">
        <label for="name2">Name: *
            <input name="name2" type="text" value="" />
        </label>

        <label for="attending2">Attending?: *
            <input name="attending2" type="radio" value="Yes" />Yes
            <input name="attending2" type="radio" value="No" />No
        </label>
        <label for="dietary2">Dietary Requirements?: *
            <input type="checkbox" name="dietary2" value="veggie">Veggie<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="dietary2" value="allergies">Allergies (Please State)<br>
            <textarea style="margin: 2px; width: 177px; height: 34px;" name="allergies2"></textarea>
        </label>



        <label for="notes2">Notes (high chair/booster seat/childs meal/ etc.): *
            <textarea style="margin: 2px; width: 177px; height: 34px;" name="notes2"></textarea>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div id="rsvp4">
        <label for="name3">Name: *
            <input name="name3" type="text" value="" />
        </label>

        <label for="attending3">Attending?: *
            <input name="attending3" type="radio" value="Yes" />Yes
            <input name="attending3" type="radio" value="No" />No
        </label>
        <label for="dietary3">Dietary Requirements?: *
            <input type="checkbox" name="dietary3" value="veggie">Veggie<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="dietary3" value="allergies">Allergies (Please State)<br>
            <textarea style="margin: 2px; width: 177px; height: 34px;" name="allergies3"></textarea>
        </label>



        <label for="notes3">Notes (high chair/booster seat/childs meal/ etc.): *
            <textarea style="margin: 2px; width: 177px; height: 34px;" name="notes3"></textarea>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div id="rsvp4">
        <label for="name4">Name: *
            <input name="name4" type="text" value="" />
        </label>

        <label for="attending4">Attending?: *
            <input name="attending4" type="radio" value="Yes" />Yes
            <input name="attending4" type="radio" value="No" />No
        </label>
        <label for="dietary4">Dietary Requirements?: *
            <input type="checkbox" name="dietary4" value="veggie">Veggie<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="dietary4" value="allergies">Allergies (Please State)<br>
            <textarea style="margin: 2px; width: 177px; height: 34px;" name="allergies4"></textarea>
        </label>



        <label for="notes4">Notes (high chair/booster seat/childs meal/ etc.): *
            <textarea style="margin: 2px; width: 177px; height: 34px;" name="notes4"></textarea>
        </label>
    </div>
    <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="1" />

    <input type="submit" />

</form>
```

So for example when the 1 radio button is shown just the rsvp1 div will be shown (With div 2, 3, 4 and 5 hidden). When the 2 radio button is pressed rsvp2 and 1 would be shown etc.

I know I can use:

```
   document.getElementById(rsvp1).style.visibility="visible";
```

But how would I set the script up to go with the radio button change.

This will be added to a wordpress site if it makes any difference

Comment: is the getElementById(rsvp1) a typo? it should be getElementById('rsvp1')

Comment: As a first step I would add elements if needed, not hide if not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is the following:

```
function showRSVP() {
    // caching the changed element (whose change event called the function):
    var checked = this,

        // getting the value of that changed element, and changing it to a
        // number (in base-10):
        n = parseInt(checked.value, 10),

        // getting all the 'div' elements whose id starts with 'rsvp':
        rsvpElems = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="rsvp"]'),

        // initialising a variable for use later:
        tmp;

    // iterating over the collection of elements we found earlier:
    for (var i = 0, len = rsvpElems.length; i < len; ++i){

        // storing the current element over which we're iterating:
        tmp = rsvpElems[i];

        // if i < n we're showing the rsvp element, otherwise we're hiding it:
        tmp.style.display = i < n ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
}

// getting all the inputs with type="radio" and name="number":
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="number"][type="radio"]');

// iterating over that collection:
for (var i = 0, len = radios.length; i < len; i++){
    // binding an change event-handler to those radio elements
    radios[i].addEventListener('change', showRSVP);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AhD3A/).

Or you could use event-delegation and bind the event-handler to the parent `<label>` element instead:

```
function showRSVP(e) {
    // caching the changed-element (e is the event automagically passed
    // to the function), e.target is the element upon which the event
    // originated:
    var checked = e.target,
        n = parseInt(checked.value, 10),
        rsvpElems = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="rsvp"]'),
        tmp;

    for (var i = 0, len = rsvpElems.length; i < len; ++i){
        tmp = rsvpElems[i];
        tmp.style.display = i < n ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
}

// getting a reference to the relevant 'label' element:
var label = document.querySelector('label[for="number"]');

// adding a change event-listener:
label.addEventListener('change', showRSVP);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AhD3A/1/).

References:

- [Attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score 1):

This would be a bit easier with a library like jQuery. Anyway, it's easy enough with straight javascript.

```
<input id="number1" name="number" type="radio" value="1" />1
<input id="number2" name="number" type="radio" value="2" />2
<input id="number3" name="number" type="radio" value="3" />3
<input id="number4" name="number" type="radio" value="4" />4
<input id="number5" name="number" type="radio" value="5" />5

<script type="text/javascript">
    for( var i = 1; i<6; i++) {
        document.getElementById('number'+i).onchange = function() {
            var index = parseInt(this.value);       
            for( var j = 1; j<6; j++)
              document
                .getElementById('rsvp'+j)
                   .style.display= j > index ? 'none':'block';

        };
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that IE8- does not support addEventListener. I used onchange (or onclick) to ensure compatibility with older versions if IE. Anyone still on XP cannot upgrade to IE9 which is the first version of IE to support addEventListener.

Comment: Anyone still on XP has bigger problems to worry about than their inability to use `addEventListener()`.

Comment: @DavidThomas That's an entirely different conversation. Considering that 1/3 of all Internet Explorer users are still running IE8, there is some relevance to accommodating it, especially since it's relatively easy to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

Implemented with vanila js.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AbDF5/)

```
window.onload = function() {

    for (var i = 1; i <= 4; ++ i)
    {
        (function(index) {
          document.getElementById("radioSelector" + index).addEventListener('click', function(){
             for (var j = 1; j <=4; ++ j) {
               var rsvpElement = document.getElementById('rsvp' + j);
               if (j <= index){
                  rsvpElement.style.display = 'block';  
               } else {
                  rsvpElement.style.display = 'none';
               }

             }
          });
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this but I need to display for example when 3 is clicked rsvp1 AND rsvp2 AND rsvp3

Comment: updated the answer, is that something that you are looking for?

Comment: try window.onload function. window.onload does not work in jsfiddle.

Comment: Still not working, I have <script type="text/javascript">`your script here`</script> at the bottom of my wordpress page and the form as you have it in fiddle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51610/discussion-between-zac-powell-and-myp3uk)

Comment: I can't join the chat unfortunately, but can you tell if you are getting any errors? with crhome developer tools, or firebug?

Answer (score -3):

using jquery you can :

```
$(#id).change(
     function () { 
         $('#rsvp1').hide(); 
      }
);
```